# How to add code-coverage for PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket, devops

My source code is in bitbucket repo and we are running azure devops pipeline using powershell script. How to provide code codecoverage for my powershell scripts?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by `provide code codecoverage for my powershell scripts`? Is it simply a `PSScript.ps1` file in your Bitbucket repo and you want to execute it  in Azure Pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket itself isn't necessarily significant in this scenario. If you have a pipeline and you are running PowerShell Tests written in Pester, you need to modify the PesterConfiguration to support test output and code coverage, as outlined at https://pester.dev/docs/usage/code-coverage

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  display: 'Run PowerShell Tests'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      $baseDirectory = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      Push-Location $baseDirectory

      $container = New-PesterContainer `
         -Path (Get-ChildItem $baseDirectory -Include "*.Tests.ps1" -Recurse).FullName `
         -Data @{ Name = "$(Build.DefinitionName)" }

      $configuration = [PesterConfiguration]@{
        Run = @{
          Container = $container
          ExcludePath = (Get-ChildItem $baseDirectory -Include "*.psm1" -Recurse).FullName 
        }
        TestResult = @{
          Enabled = $true
          OutputFormat = "NUnitXml"
          OutputPath = (Join-Path "$(Agent.TempDirectory)" "TestResults.xml")
        }
        CodeCoverage = @{
          Enabled = $true
          OutputFormat = "JaCoCo"
          OutputPath = (Join-Path "$(Agent.TempDirectory)" "Pester-Coverage.xml")
        }
      }
  
      Invoke-Pester -Configuration $configuration

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Unit Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultFormat: 'NUnit'
    testResultFiles: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestResults.xml'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish Code Coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/Pester-Coverage.xml'
    pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

The above is assuming your tests are in the root of your repository.